# Adding permission to specific users to access specific directories

Tags: debian, file-permissions, users

I am using Debian. I've got these three directories:

- /home/Server1/files
- /home/Server2/files
- /home/Server3/files

And I've got these users:

- User1
- User2
- User3

What I want to do:
Make specific user have full access (create, write, edit) to specific directories (and everything inside of them)
[user_name][accessible_directories]

- [User1][Server1, Server2, Server3]
- [User2][Server1, Server3]
- [User3][Server2]

I don't want to mess something up, so I really need help from experienced users.
Could you write short step-by-step tutorial?

- Create User1, User2, User3.
- Type command: ...
- Type command: ...
- Etc.

Comment: You will need ACL, see here: https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions#Access_Control_Lists_in_Linux

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options: ACLs, or well-designed groups, or a combination of the two.

The well-designed groups is probably the least fragile of these (if root touches the files, ACLs might not applied).

If you invert your mapping, you get:

- server1: user1, user2
- server2: user1, user3
- server3: user1, user2

So we simply map each directory to a group.

```
# create groups
groupadd server1
groupadd server2
groupadd server3
# create users
useradd -G server1,server2,server3 -m user1
useradd -G server1,server3 -m user2
useradd -G server2 -m user3
# create directories
mkdir -p /home/Server{1,2,3}/files
chgrp server1 /home/Server1/files
chgrp server2 /home/Server2/files
chgrp server3 /home/Server3/files
# set permissions on the directories
chmod u=rwx,g=rwxS,o=x /home/Server*/files
```

The setgid (g=S) bit is really critical here. It will ensure that new files in a given directory are given the same group as existing files.

There is one last caveat with the above: it works best if your users have a umask of 0002, rather than the generic 0022. If they have a stricter umask (eg 0077), it will break. ACLs will also generally break in that case.